# How to iterate an unordered_set from the end to the begin

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to iterate an unordered_set from the end to the begin:

```
unordered_set<Expression*> BlocExpressions;

for(auto it=BlocExpressions.end(); it != BlocExpressions.begin(); it--)
{
    //do some work
}
```

But there is no `operator--` declared.

So, should I code the `operator--`, or is there a way to do that?

Comment: what's the point to iterate from end to begin, as unordered_set doesn't have the key ordering for the elements ?

Comment: The "unordered" in there should have been a hint. ;-) (Yes, I fell for that myself just now, typing out the `rbegin()` before thought set in.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `std::unordered_set`, the order in which you iterate through the elements does not matter. Saying that, you could just imagine the order is random. You get no particular order regardless you do a forward iteration or backward iteration. That's why it provides no reverse iterator nor provides the `--` operator overload for normal iterator. Forward and backward iterations have the same semantics here: to iterate in a random order.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand why you use words "end" and "begin" for unordered_set. unordered_set does not have [particular order](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/). You can iterate all elements by using iterator object. 
If you need order in the set, you should use other container, for example [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

Comment: Isn't this a little disingenuous? I see your point, but [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) does after all provide members named `begin` and `end`.

Answer (score -1):

I also find it curious why there is no rbegin() and rend(). I am using unordered_set to add random numbers (unordered) to represent a certain path.
That would be great.

The solution I have found, it might help someone else is the following one. Adding the decrement in the first argument of the for loop:
`auto it = --BlocExpressions.end()`

```cpp
unordered_set<Expression*> BlocExpressions;

for(auto it = --BlocExpressions.end(); ; it--){   

    //do some work

    // This will include the last item (which is BlocExpressions.begin())
    if(it == BlocExpressions.begin()){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, as the question states, std::unordered_set::iterator does not have a decrement operator defined.  BlocExpressions.end() returns such an iterator, so this code should not compile.

Comment: I do have exactly this code implemented and it compiled and runs nicely. If you are interested I recommend you also trying to do it, let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Yes, I had checked beforehand, and have again now. Your implementation seems to work in x64 MSVC v19.31, but not in Clang or GCC. While MSVC might have implemented a decrement iterator, the standard only requires that std::unordered_set::iterator satisfies the requirements of a LegacyForwardIterator. Implementing the decrement operator is not one of those requirements. My test code is here: https://godbolt.org/z/cGEozTjPv